# How to make a if else conditions to redirect in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, header-files

Basically I can’t return a css, js, image or fonts with php as a result of a request, because it’s read by the browser as a html file, so, I am trying to do a if else condition in the .htaccess to redirect a request, so I don’t  have to deal with those files in php.

Additionally, I need to force the https no matter what.
I am using Apache/2.2.31 so I can’t use the syntax `<If "true"> </If>`.

Optional is deal with the request header, so the browser can read the file the true type, but I don’t know how.

I am very new with .htaccess, and I am pretty sure this should by easy.

Here is the code:

```
RewriteEngine On

#this is just to forcing https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]

# if css, js, html, images and fonts, do not redirect anything
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png|woff?2|otf|html)$ [NC]
RewriteRule  # I don't know how to do anything

# else if the folder is “admin”, don’t do anything
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /admin/([^\s?]*) [NC] 
RewriteRule  # I don't know how to do anything

# else if the file is php or a folder, redirect to public folder
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,NE,R=302]
RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can you add the redirection you want to achieve as an example?

Comment: Of course you can return whatever content you want by means of php, nut just html, _if you specify the correct mime type_ ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is the pretty close that you want

```
RewriteEngine On

# this is just to forcing https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

# IF the folder is “admin”, don’t do anything
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /admin/(.*) [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
# END IF

# IF the file is PHP or a folder, redirect to the public folder
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\.php$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https://%{HTTP_HOST}/public/$1" [R=302,L]
# ELSE if file is css, js, html, images and fonts, do not redirect anything
    # Do nothing
# END IF
```

Redirect results:

```
http://example.com/admin/index.php --> https://example.com/admin/index.php
http://example.com/index.php --> https://example.com/public/index.php
http://example.com/main.js --> https://example.com/main.js
```

Demo: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=9a712335-897f-57d3-9127-3bc5d747c0a7

Documentation: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html

Comment: With some minor modifications, work perfectly, thanks so much